# Problema ao enviar arquivo por FTP C#

Tags: c#, ftp

Tenho um executável que envia um arquivo .CSV via FTP para meu cliente.

Rodando em minha maquina local funciona tudo tranquilo mas quando roda no servidor do meu cliente não funciona.

Sempre que cai na linha

```
request.GetRequestStream()
```

recebo a mensagem de erro

> Unable to connect to the remote server

Segue o código da minha aplicação

```
string pathArquivoConsumoFull = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", arquivoData[0].DirectoryName, arquivoData[0].Name);

Console.WriteLine("patharquivoConsumo - " + pathArquivoConsumoFull);

FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(enderecoFTP + "/" + Path.GetFileName(arquivoData[0].Name));
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(nomeUsuarioFTP, passFTP);
request.UsePassive = true;
request.UseBinary = true;
request.KeepAlive = false;

var stream = File.OpenRead(pathArquivoConsumoFull);
byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
stream.Close();

Console.WriteLine("Entra no reqStream");

using (var reqStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    reqStream.Close();
}

Console.WriteLine("Passou reqStream!!!");
```

Instalei o FileZila no servidor e tenho acesso ao endereço FTP para *upload* e *download*.

Comment: Não tem como te ajudar sem saber detalhes da máquina. Verifique _firewall_, _proxy_ essas coisas. Se o _firewall_ tiver bloqueando as portas entre **60000** e **61000** é este o problema.

Comment: Desculpa minha ignorância, se as potas entre 60000 e 61000 estivem bloqueadas, o FileZila não ia conseguir conectar?

Comment: Depende das regras do _firewall_. Pode estar bloqueado e ter uma regra liberando todas as portas pro _FileZilla_.

Comment: Criei novas regras para o intervalo de portas.
verifiquei e o Firewall state do perfil esta Off.
 Continua com o mesmo erro. alguma outra dica?

Comment: Específica não. Tente abrir o FTP pelo _browser_ também, verifique se não é alguma restrição com sua aplicação.

Comment: tbm Tenho acesso pelo browser.

Comment: O que mostra o _stacktrace_?

Comment: Assim que entra na linha GetRequestStream() a tenho a Exception  "Unable to connect to the remote server "
tentei pegar o log do InnerException mas vem null

Comment: E o _stacktrace_?

Comment: Ql o valor de endereço ftp nos dois casos?

Comment: @jbueno vem null

Comment: Inclui uma linha e agora o stacktrace retorna 
at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.ChekError()

Answer (score 1):

Eu o utilizo o seguinte método para UPLOAD e roda no servidor do cliente sem problemas, faça uma comparação ou até um teste de acordo com suas necessidades e veja o resultado.

```
    public static Byte[] StartUploadsFtp(out string pstrMsg, out bool pbooRetorno, string pstrDiretorioArq, int pnuEndRemotoFtp)
    {
        pstrMsg = default(String);
        pbooRetorno = default(Boolean);
        byte[] buffer = default(Byte[]);

        try
        {
            DataTable dt = Dal.SelectInfoConfigFtpDAL(out pstrMsg, out pbooRetorno, pnuEndRemotoFtp);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0 && dt.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(pstrDiretorioArq);

                var strUsuario = dt.Rows[0]["ftp_usuario"].ToString();
                var strSenha = dt.Rows[0]["ftp_senha"].ToString();
                var strServidor = dt.Rows[0]["ftp_servidor"].ToString();
                var strDiretorioFtp = dt.Rows[0]["diretorio_ftp"].ToString();

                using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(pstrDiretorioArq))
                {
                    buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];

                    fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    // Cria o XML do arquivo Txt, para fazer o Upload para o FTP
                    Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format(@"{0}//{1}//{2}", strServidor, strDiretorioFtp, fileInfo.Name));

                    // Criando uma requisição FTP
                    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(uri);
                    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(strUsuario, strSenha);
                    request.KeepAlive = false;
                    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                    request.UseBinary = true;
                    request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

                    // Escreve no arquivo
                    using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                        pbooRetorno = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                pstrMsg = string.Format("Não foram encontrados os dados de configuração do FTP.");

                pbooRetorno = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            pstrMsg = string.Format("Erro:\nMétodo 'StartUploads'\nDetalhes: {0}", ex.Message);

            pbooRetorno = false;
        }
        return buffer;
    }
```

Comment: Qual valor você passa na (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(??);

Comment: Passo o meu como ftp://54.207.102.23:21/pub/lerColeta/nomearquivo.csv
 mas tenho certeza que esse não é o problema

Comment: Eu passo esse o objeto uri que é criado logo acima. Ele recebe algo do tipo: ftp: //cliente.dd.texto.com://diretorio_Ftp//nomeArquivo

Comment: Talvez seja as permissões do meu exe, quando executo  ele clicando 2x funciona. quando chamo ele a partir e um procedimento no banco, não funciona

Answer (score -1):

O problema era o usuário que executava meu processo no Job, ele não tinha as credenciais necessária para abrir uma conexão com o endereço FTP do cliente

Comment: Works in my machine é um caso clássico de negligenciar os requisitos de direitos e regras de validação/verificação de falhas.